# CLang error (objective C): value stored during initialization is never read

Tags: objective-c, clang-static-analyzer

```
Foo *oFoo = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This is how I was taught to program in Objective C, yet the CLang error checker complains that the initial value was never read. But oFoo is an object with properties. oFoo itself has no single value. The property values are what matter.

```
oFoo.PropertyA = 1;
oFoo.PropertyB = @"Hello, World."
```

Should I just ignore this? Is this worth fixing? What is the fix, seeing that "initial value" is meaningless in my context?

Comment: What do you do with oFoo when the method ends?

Comment: Would be nice if you give complete code of the method that contains this. And, btw, did you try to switch to other compiler?

Comment: oFoo autoreleases when the method ends. This code sample is sufficient to illustrate the question. No, I'm not a tinkerer with compilers. That's way too low-level for where I am right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually that means:

1. You've created a variable.
2. You've assigned some value to a variable. Doesn't matter, to itself or to it's properties.
3. You've "recreated" this value or finished block (method/for-each/etc.).

For a simple type:

```
int a;
a = 2;
a = 3;
```

First value (2) is never used. Similar things can happen with objects, for example:

```
Foo *oFoo = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];

oFoo.PropertyA = 1;
oFoo.PropertyB = @"Hello, World."

oFoo = [[[Foo alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Here first alloc-init block created a value that was overridden by second alloc-init. And error tells something like that.

Instead of second alloc-init block I can close method implementation, that will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think Alexander Babaev may be right. Here's actual code:

```
Part *oPart = [[[Part alloc] init] autorelease];
iParts = aParts.count;
for (iPart=0;iPart<iParts;iPart++) {
    oPart = [aParts objectAtIndex:iPart];
```

aPart is an array of Part objects. Maybe I should eliminate the first line and the last line should look like this:

```
Part *oPart = [aParts objectAtIndex:iPart];
```

If I do that, I DO NOT have to explicitly release oPart at the end of the loop. By declaring oPart before the loop begins, I was trying to be efficient and just reuse the oPart object, rather than create/release each time through the loop.

Anybody know which is the better approach?

Comment: In that case the first line should just be:  Part *oPart = nil;, although the rest of code makes no sense to me - after the loop is done oPart will point to just the very last element in aParts.  The same code would be to say: Part *oPart = [aParts lastElement];

Comment: There is no object creation within that loop, it's setting a ptr to pre-existing members of the `aParts` array. You may be confusing Objective-C with some other language :) and I suggest you revisit some Objective-C object creation fundamentals. Another indication of that, your earlier comment "oFoo autoreleases when the method ends" is also wrong. The lifetime of autorelease objects is not linked to their scope but they last until the pool is drained, usually when call stack unwinds all the way to the app's run loop (ie. event loop). This is what makes it ok to return autoreleased objects.