# Memory Leak warning

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I have an array declared inside a user defined method. I use this array to store the values returned from the sqlite database. Then I use that value for further processing... But Xcode gives me the following warning at the array declaration.
"Value stored during initialization is never being read"
Here is my code:

```
 NSMutableArray *tempId=[NSMutableArray array];
NSString *sqlStr1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select deck_id from decksTable limit '%d' offset '%d'",1,deckID-1];
char *sql1 = (char*)[sqlStr1 UTF8String];
tempId=[appDelegate.dbConnection  fetchColumnFromTable:sql1 col:0];
NSNumber *tempint1 =[tempId objectAtIndex:0];
int actualDeckID=[tempint1 intValue];
```

Please help me out of this.

Note dbConnection is the database connection object and fetchColumnFromTable is a user defined method which returns the array of values fetched from database. Then i get the first value in NSNumber and convert it into integer to use it in my code. I get the above warnning at the declaration of the tempId array.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646582/clang-error-objective-c-value-stored-during-initialization-is-never-read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSMutableArray *tempId=[NSMutableArray array];` is not necessary as the memory allocated by this statement is not used and you are pointing tempId to the array returned at `tempId=[appDelegate.dbConnection  fetchColumnFromTable:sql1 col:0];`. So basically you can just declare the array and not initialise it. `NSMutableArray *tempId;`